# Elastic search functionScore vs sort by script

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic4s

I want to change the score of the results from query. I can change the result by boosting and filtering. However, I can do this both function score and script query. What is the difference between them?

For example: 
`functionScoreQuery(someQuery).scorers(scriptScore(....))`
and 
`sort(scriptSort(.....))`

Answer (score 3):

A function scorer can be applied to a subset of the results by applying a filter. The sort will be applied to all results in the search. So if you say wanted everything in `London` to have one script score, and everything in `Paris` another, you could do that with function scorers.